# Should I vote to close a question that was answered by a comment?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677111/django-ubuntu-server-nginx-gunicorn-server-error-500#comment64747674_38677111).

It feels like it could be an example of a question that is asking "why isn't my code working?"

I'm hesitant to make that vote because it does have a specific problem statement (500 error) per the description of that vote to close reason. On the other hand, that error could be caused by anything. In the comments it turns out the error had nothing to do with the posted server config.

Should I vote to close a question like this that gets answered in the comments, often due to a typo or other error unrelated to the question? If so, what is the proper reason I should specify?

Comment: Why would haven been answered in a comment be a reason to close a question? You should vote to close based on merits (or lack thereof) of the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza to state the obvious, it is because _in general_ a question that can be answered by a one-line comment is asking something that is very simplistic or something unrelated to the question being asked. For instance, the example I provided shows a question whose answer is unrelated to the info provided in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the close reason

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. *While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.*

(emphasis mine) applies. This is usually (but not always) the case for questions which can be solved by short comments.